# Javascript parameter is not defined

Tags: javascript

So I try to make a collection of buttons, which print out a hello and the name of the button. The code below doesn't work because "Uncaught ReferenceError: Mike is not defined". Its a parameter, how do I even define it?

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello to Mike" onClick="hello(Mike);" />
```

and the JS is something like this:

```
function hello(name) {
... }
```

I have another button where clicking doesnt send any parameters and it works just as intended.

edit: Putting Mike in quotations produces another error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list". I am doing this as a homework and we are required to write the html with javascript, below is my modified, whole line of code which is throwing the error.

```
 document.write('<input type="button" value="Say hello to Mike" onClick="hello('Mike');" />');
```

could the document.type be the cause of the problem? Between these 2 errors, I do literally nothing else than add the quotation marks in the code.

edit2: It finally worked after I added \ before the quotation marks.

Comment: Put single quotes around `Mike`, if it's to be parsed as a literal.

Comment: Put Mike in single quotes

Comment: As is apparent by the syntax coloring your string does not include Mike. To use the `'` character in a string bounded by the same character you need to escape it i.e. `... hello(\'Mike\')...`

Comment: Try this  document.write('<input type="button" value="Say hello to Mike" onClick="hello(\'Mike\');" />');

Comment: Vishal: that works. Goddamn, what a stupid error.. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Mike is a string, correct syntax would be

```
onClick="hello('Mike');"
```

Since there are no quotes, javascript treating that as a variable.

Comment: I also tried that, all the javascript on my test site disappears if I do it like that.

Comment: Ahh yes, its "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list". It isn't missing though, literally the only thing I chanced was add the quotes.

Comment: @Codereerer can you please update with question with the erorr and your code related to that

Answer (score 0):

Declare as a String in `Mike` .In your code The mike act like a variable .So the java-script check this variable defined or not. So only Its throw the Mike is undefined.

```js
function hello(name) {
console.log(name)
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Say hello to Mike" onClick="hello('Mike');" />
```

Answer (score 0):

when you user the function hello,param 'Mike' error,
the correct writer:

you write this,system think it's a variable